# Code giving error in switching letters out for eachother

Tags: arrays, c, string, char

The code is glitching out when i'm trying to do a simple character exchange. The code is listed down below along with screen shots of the error.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char Ghost[12] = "SimonGhost";
    int ghostdeathdate = 5;
    char Price;
    int Soap;
    while (ghostdeathdate > 0)
    {
        scanf("%c %d", &Price, &Soap);
        Ghost[Soap] = Price;
        printf("%s\n", Ghost);
        --ghostdeathdate;
    }
    return ghostdeathdate;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Don't post error message as images. Post it as text.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the [new line left](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5240789/1606345) in the buffer in each call to `scanf`, you need to consume each new line with a space:

```
scanf("%c %d", &Price, &Soap);
```

should be

```
scanf(" %c %d", &Price, &Soap); // Notice a space before %c
```

Comment: OK it works! TYSM Just to ask so the code needs a space in the inverted commas for it to work?

Comment: I have edited/added a link to relevant information.

Comment: @SethManuel yes, the leading space consumes all blank spaces: `' '`, `'\t'`  and `'\n'`